# Lucene не работает поиск "шаблон" и "*"

Tags: java, lucene

Я использую Lucene 8.9.0.

Например у меня есть шаблон **ABC** и я хочу найти **ABCaaa**, для этого я использую оператор "*" и мой запрос на поиск выглядит так: **ABC***.

Но при этом если, я хочу найти **aaaABC**, я предполагаю, что надо оператор "*" поставить перед **ABC**, чтобы запрос выглядел так: "***ABC**".

Я ставлю оператор звездочка перед моим шаблоном, выполняю запрос:

```
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(rword.getSearchField(), getAnalyzer());
        Query query = null;
        TopDocs topDocs = null;
        try{

            query = parser.parse("*ABC"); 
            topDocs = searcher.search(query, 100);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            
            System.out.println("[ERROR - inMemoryLuceneIndex] Ошибка поиска шаблона: "+rword.getOriginalView());
            System.out.println("Возможная причина: неправильно задан шаблон. Возможно в нем есть символы: 1)/  ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;
        for (ScoreDoc hit : hits) { //Пройтись по найденным документам из индекса
            handleHit(hit, query, reader, searcher, curDoc, rword, categ, isMetadata, isShortText);
        }
```

и код переходит в секцию catch(), где я вижу такое сообщение об ошибки данной операции:

```
org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Cannot parse '*ABC': '*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:114)
    at com.mycompany.stackexp.Rubricator.CustomIndex.query_OneWord(CustomIndex.java:192)
    at com.mycompany.stackexp.Rubricator.Rubricator.toRubricateContent(Rubricator.java:234)
    at com.mycompany.stackexp.TaskCallable.call(TaskCallable.java:209)
    at com.mycompany.stackexp.TaskCallable.call(TaskCallable.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: '*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.getWildcardQuery(QueryParserBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(QueryParserBase.java:820)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:469)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:355)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:244)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:215)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:109)
    ... 8 more
```

Так же я пробовал выполнять запрос таким образом:

```
query = parser.parse("/*ABC");
```

Но все равно ошибка

При этом я нашел описание, которое дало мне новое видение моей ситуации:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_regex

Основная мысль с этого сайта для меня:

```
suffix:

Term fragment comes after * or ?, with a forward slash to delimit the construct. 
For example, search=/.*numeric./ returns "alphanumeric".
```

Там написано, что можно попробовать переформировать запрос, тем самым мой новый запрос выглядеть так: "/.*ABC./"

```
query = parser.parse("*ABC");
```

При этом ошибки нет, но и нет нахождения.

---

Подскажите как можно решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Так вы проверяли шаблон `"/.*ABC/"` или нет: `query = parser.parse("/.*ABC/")`?

Comment: Нет в подобной форме не проверял, то сейчас протестировал и это работает, большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если необходимо выполнить поиск и найти первую часть слова, когда известна только вторая часть слова (или также видел название поиск по suffix), то можно воспользоваться RegexpQuery.

Если используете RegexpQuery, то ваш запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
    RegexpQuery query = new RegexpQuery(new Term("НАЗВАНИЕ-ПОЛЯ-ПО-КОТОРОМУ-ИДЕТ-ПОИСК", ".*ШАБЛОН"));
```

---

2. Но также можно использовать и обычный Query, он сам сможет определить, что это RegexpQuery, но чтобы он смог это сделать **важно**, чтобы ваш запрос был таким:

```
    Query query = parser.parse("/.*ШАБЛОН/");
```

В данном случае Query понимает, что это именно RegexpQuery по "обрамлению", имеется ввиду такие два символа: "/."  - спереди и получается один символ "/" - сзади.